# I need .png file with transparency but when I export file as .png I get black background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, website-design, transparency, png

I need .png file with transparency for web but when I export file as .png I get black background?
I am working in Photoshop and Illustrator.

Comment: yes and I think is ok. I see transparency but when I upload that  same file in facebook like profile picture I just get black image.

Comment: For a Facebook profile it doesn't need to be transparent. A white background is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows photo viewer previews transparancies with black background.

Your .PNG will show transparent background if you view it over color in illustrator or other graphics programs.

[image]

If this is not true for you make sure your export (save for web) are set to  transparency:

[image]

Comment: I have black logo and when I export to .png file i just get black image. I tried to upload to facebook and I just get black image.  Same thing happens when I export .png from Photoshop and Illustrator.